# How to see Swift object properties in Objective-C project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, macos

I'm having Objective-C project and i'd like to try Swift in it. I was able to configure it to use Swift classes. Anyway i can't see Swift object properties while debugging:

[image]

I've even overriden `description` property to print all the variables:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

@objc
public class Mcu : NSObject, Mappable {
    var name : String?
    var arch : String?
    var macro : String?
    var libraryName : String?

    required public init?(_ map: Map) {
    }

    // Mappable
    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        name        <- map["name"]
        arch        <- map["arch"]
        macro       <- map["macro"]
        libraryName <- map["libraryName"]
    }

    override public var description : String {
        return "name=\(name), arch=\(arch), macro=\(macro), libraryName=\(libraryName)"
    }
}
```

If i print object in log (`NSLog([mcus[0] description])`) i
m getting correct string:

```
2015-11-01 10:27:19.262 Project[1447:261056] name=Optional("avr2"), arch=Optional("ARCH_AVR2"), macro=nil, libraryName=Optional("\"s8515\"")
```

It's not the solution to convert to Swift all the project as it's pretty large.. What can i do to provide convenient debugging for both Obj-C and Swift in Obj-C project?

PS. Xcode 7.1

PPS. For Swift class `Mcu` Xcode generates according Obj-c header and it looks correct (but there is difference for debugger):

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC17ProjectModule3Mcu")
@interface Mcu : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * __nullable name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * __nullable arch;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * __nullable macro;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * __nullable libraryName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * __nonnull description;
@end
```

Comment: same question~~